# Facebook Events Manager saying "Ouch! Something went wrong..." when trying to load events

Tags: facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I added the Facebook iOS SDK to my iOS app, and then my Events Manager said I had successfully completed the 2 below steps:

1. Add Facebook SDK
2. Release app on the App Store

After I released my latest version with the SDK, my Events Manager seemed to be ready to accept events. However a few days after, events have been failing to load (see screenshot below):

[image]

It says "Oops Something went wrong..." but doesn't say what.

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Have you solved it?

Comment: Facebook had to manually log in to my account and fix the problem @Kuzma